# How can I show multiple megento stores in front end?

Tags: magento

I have 2 stores called 'Retail' and 'Wholesale'. While adding product I have to select the store (It can be both the store or none or any one), and i have to add price for different store . If am selecting both the stores, `how can I add different price for sores ?`

How can I select sore In the product ?

While adding store we selects Category, I can manage store here but how will I display different price for same product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has three levels of scope (listed below in ascending order of precedence):

- Global (aka Default Configuration)
- Website
- Store (aka Store View)

There are also two scope contexts: system configuration and entity.

Note that not all sysconfig options or entity data can be set at each level. Product pricing is one such datum. In System Configuration > Catalog, product price can be configured as either global scope or website scope, but *not* store scope. To achieve store scope-like behavior, configure pricing to have website scope, assign each store to its own website, and set the price at the website level.